# how to put javascript variable in php inside the javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript code that I wanna put a php on it.Then in middle of php code , put a javascript variable.

like this :

```
 <script>
function getuserid(id,shop){
...
    var htmlString="<?php $_SESSION['SELECTED_CID']= {I want to put 'id' variable here}?>";
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Understand that javascript is client side code, PHP is server side code... this is not going to happen.

Comment: Google for AJAX. It's the only way to get JS talking to PHP.

Comment: You can render a PHP value inside JavaScript inside a PHP file very easily. But I am not sure what `id` is - can you explain OP?

Comment: Thank you all.id is a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP code was compiled and run once when you done loading your page. But javascript function can be used many time! So, some function like this does not exist.

You can use Ajax to accomplish what you want, whenever you wanna retrieve UserID, you can call an ajax, then ajax do a request to server and return you what you need!

Have a try :)